# Clear Text on single tap

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, searchbar

When I click on the cross icon first time, it lowers the keyboard and on the second tap, it clears the text in the search bar. I wanted to clear the text on the first tap I have tried other solutions as well but nothing worked. How can i clear the text on the first click?

```
    return (
      <View style={styles.FlatList_header}>
        <View style={styles.header_style}>
          <Input
            autoFocus={true}
            style={styles.textInputStyle}
            onChangeText={text => this.search(text)}
            value={this.state.text}
          />
          <Icon
            name="close"
            style={styles.crossIcon}
            onPress={() => {
              this.search('');
            }}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  };

  render() {
    const {data, onPress} = this.props;
    return (
      <>
        <SafeAreaView
          style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: customColor.defaultGreen}}>
          <View style={styles.MainContainer}>
            <FlatList
              data={data}
              renderItem={({item}) => (
                <View
                  style={{
                    flex: 1,
                    borderWidth: 0.5,
                    borderColor: customColor.textLightGrey,
                  }}>
                  <Text
                    style={styles.FlatList_Item}
                    onPress={() => onPress(item)}>
                    {item?.taskName}
                  </Text>
                </View>
              )}
              enableEmptySections={true}
              ListHeaderComponent={this.Render_FlatList_Sticky_header}
              keyExtractor={item => item.id}
            />
          </View>
        </SafeAreaView>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your onPress function do this.

```
     onPress={() => {
     Keyboard.dismiss()
              this.search('');
     this.setState(text: '')
           }}
```

Also, you are not setting your state while `onChangeText`, Do this in your `onChangeText`

```
onChangeText={(text)=>this.setState({text})}
```

Edit: Add this into your FlatList

```
 keyboardShouldPersistTaps='always'
```

Comment: Please specify your platform and this will be great if you share a snack on the expo. or share me a compete class and I will make a snack on the expo and share it with you with a solution.

Comment: ```  search = text => {
    this.setState({text});
    this.props.onSearch(text);
  };
``` i am setting state in search function

Comment: Yes, maybe but your provided information is not sufficient, Either show me your complete code of class where you doing all these things or paste you're all code here
https://snack.expo.io/ and share with me the URL.

Comment: Specific platform where you are facing this issue on the same on both?

Comment: i am facing it on android

Comment: there are so many errors in your code and also you haven't placed all of the components there in the snack like styles file is not present there.

Comment: Your problem is fixed here also I edit my answer with the change I had to do in your code. https://snack.expo.io/@waheed25/220a33

Comment: Please follow this one.

https://snack.expo.io/@waheed25/220a33

Answer (score 0):

Create a new state for ex: **pressed**.
If user touch the first time set true. And insert the if condition in the view.

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setState({ pressed: !this.state.pressed})}>
{this.state.pressed ? (
    <Icon
    name="close"
    style={styles.crossIcon}
    onPress={() => {
        this.search('');
    }}
/>
) : (
    <Text>Clear</Text>
)}
</TouchableOpacity>
```